# Can memwatch-next be used in Production App?

Tags: node.js, express, node-memwatch

Lately I am facing a memory leak in my node app, but I am failing to identify its source on my local machine. I was wondering whether [memwatch-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch-next) is safe to use in my Production App or are there any performance or any other drawbacks of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we have been using memwatch-next in production environment on a site with 300K+ requests/hour for several years. There were no observable performance drawbacks and it did deliver very valuable information for identification of memory leaks